# Simplify With Assumptions Not Using Distributive Property Of Dot Product

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

Given the following expression

```
Assuming[(n | d | t) ∈ Vectors[3, Reals] && n.t == 0, FullSimplify[(n + d).t]]
```

Why does mathematica give me the below instead of simplifying to d.t?

```
(d + n).t
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add [`TensorExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorExpand.html) to achieve this:

```
Assuming[(n | d | t) ∈ Vectors[3, Reals] && n.t == 0, 
   TensorExpand[(n + d).t] // FullSimplify]

(* d.t *)
```

As I understand it, manipulating symbolic tensors should generally be done with the `Tensor*` family of functions ([guide page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SymbolicTensors.html)). This is not built-in in functions like `FullSimplify` .